# edited css does not change rmarkdown xaringan presentation

Tags: html, css, r, markdown

I'm new to CSS and attempting to edit the formatting of a RMarkdown presentation using Xaringan. One change I'd like to make is increasing the line spacing of the slide text.

Here's the relevant part of the YAML yeader of my .Rmd file:

```
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: "libs/remark-css/example.css"
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
```

And in `example.css`, I've added a `line-height` to the `body` specifications:

```
body { 
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', 'Droid Serif', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, 'Microsoft YaHei', 'Songti SC', serif; 
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

But when I go back to index.Rmd and `knit` the HTML file, the line spacing remains unchanged. The same is true if I try to change font, font size, etc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the css file located in the right place? I mean - can you make any changes in that and see them in the end result?

Comment: The .css file is definitely in the path specified in the YAML header, plus I don't think it would knit and produce a HTML document without accessing some .css file. However, none of the edits I've made to example.css seem to have any effect. Probably some stupid mistake, just not sure what!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked and it is possible to include `.css` files that are not located in the same directory as the `.Rmd` presentation file. Thus, if it isn't a problem with it not being able to find the file then it must be something with the contents of your `.css` file.

You can try to modify this example `example.css` file to suit your needs. It works and changes the background, fonts etc. Note that it is the part under `.remark-slide-content` that does the actual change.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:400,700);

/* CE Added my favorite fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya|Alegreya+Sans');

body { font-family: 'Droid Serif', 'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, 'Microsoft YaHei', 'Songti SC', serif;
       background-color:#222;
     }

/* Default background colour, and font size */
.remark-slide-content{ background-color:#222;
                       font-family: 'Fira Sans', 'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
                       color: #fff;
                       font-size: 220%;    /* Regular text */
/*                     font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif; */
                       font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;                 
                     }
```

My YAML looks like this (well part of it)

```
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: ['default', 'example.css']
```

Does that do anything for you?

Comment: Yes! That works, in that when I knit it I see your formatting as specified in the new .css file. I think the issue must be with putting the .css file anywhere but in the repository home directory (which is also where "default" lives, apparently?). Thank you!

Comment: Nope. It should work with a css file in a subdirectory. Just tried it and have updated the answer.